# Property accessed via magic method Illuminate\Http\Request object Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am taking over a previously written Laravel application and trying to learn how various things are fit together. While doing so, I found the following piece of code:

```php
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->popular) {
            //....
        }
        //...
    }
```

I am not quite sure what the if-statement is trying to access. When I hover over the `$request→popular` part, it says that `popular` attribute is being accessed through magic method. I am also not able to find any attribute/method named popular anywhere else in the code. Does anybody know what this might be trying to do?

I know that the attribute `popular` is not internal to the `Request` object because later in the code, the programmer is also accessing various other attributes using this magic method format.

Is it some sort of shorthand way of accessing a URI? (*e.g.,* perhaps `/api/popular`)

Comment: It's a request parameter. Maybe it was sent as form data or as a query string. In this case, `$request->popular` evaluates to `null` (`false`) or something else which is then casted to bool. If you're taking over the project you shuold read some [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `Input Via Dynamic Properties`. It's still on `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

For example, if one of your application's forms contains a `name` field, you may access the value of the field like so:

```php
$name = $request->name;
```

It's the same as this:

```php
$name = $request->input('name');
```

When using dynamic properties, Laravel will first look for the parameter's value in the request payload. If it is not present, Laravel will search for the field in the route parameters(like: query string.).

In your example, it may be something like this:

```
/api/posts?popular=1
```

And just in case if you wonder how is this done it the magic PHP `__get()` method.

Here is the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L696) of how is this achieved.